# How do you create a taxonomy for a product search engine by ingredients for WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I want to create a search engine for ingredients for allergy sufferers.

Unlike regular search engines that look for products related to the words you enter, this Search Engine will find the products within my catalog that do not have the ingredients we enter.
A product finder for allergens.

I've been looking for a way to do it for days and I found some ideas that suggest creating a taxonomy of the ingredients.
I also found some example of a taxonomy, but I don't understand how to create the one my search engine needs.

I'm looking for an example to implement on my site, but the first thing I'm looking for is to understand how it works and know the logic.
I understand that this is not a school, but I can't find where to learn how to create something like this, that's why you come here for advice

What should the taxonomy be like so that it finds the products that do not contain the ingredients that we enter in the search engine?

We put the ingredients of the products in the catalog in the short description of the product.
How to select these ingredients so that the search selects products that do not contain the selected ingredient?

Can you help me create the form with the taxonomy?
I have a simple simple form.

```
  <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="keywords" name="keywords" size="30" maxlength="30">
    <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Buscar">
    </form>
```

And the functionality:

```
<?php
    //Si se ha pulsado el botón de buscar
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        //Recogemos las claves enviadas
        $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    
        //Conectamos con la base de datos en la que vamos a buscar
        $conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "USUARIO", "PASSWORD");
        mysql_select_db("NOMBRE_BASE_DE_DATOS", $conexion);
    
        $query = "SELECT fecha, titulo, DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha
                    FROM TABLA
                    WHERE status = '1'
                    AND (contenido LIKE '%" . $keywords . "%'
                    OR titulo LIKE '%" . $keywords . "%')
                    ORDER BY fecha desc";
    
        $query_searched = mysql_query($query, $conexion);
    
        $count_results = mysql_num_rows($query_searched);
    
        //Si ha resultados
        if ($count_results > 0) {
    
            echo '<h2>Se han encontrado '.$count_results.' resultados.</h2>';
    
            echo '<ul>';
            while ($row_searched = mysql_fetch_array($query_searched)) {
                //En este caso solo mostramos el titulo y fecha de la entrada
                echo '<li><a href="#">'.$row_searched['titulo'].' ('.$row_searched['fecha'].')</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        else {
            //Si no hay registros encontrados
            echo '<h2>No se encuentran resultados con los criterios de búsqueda.</h2>';
        }
    }
    ?
```

> 

And I have seen some example of Taxonomy like the following, but I don't know how to make the one that is correct for my needs

```
 function wcif_register_ingredient_taxonomy() {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Ingredients', 'taxonomy general name', 'wcif' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Ingredient', 'taxonomy singular name', 'wcif' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Ingredients', 'wcif' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Ingredients', 'wcif' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Ingredient:', 'wcif' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Ingredient', 'wcif' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Ingredient Name', 'wcif' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Ingredients', 'wcif' ),
        );
    
        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'ingredient' ),
        );
    
        register_taxonomy( 'ingredient', array( 'product' ), $args );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'wcif_register_ingredient_taxonomy' );
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 (2013), and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0 (2015). Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: If my question is poorly formulated, I will delete it, but I can't find a way to make that form, and I want to learn